# Python 3 request module: .iter_content not downloading files correctly

Tags: python, download, request, python-requests

I am currently working in a project in the form of a silly gift to my girlfriend: a program that automatically downloads pictures of puppies and kitties, and other animals. (By simply changing some things, it would be capable of downloading .pdf, books, movies or whatever, so that's the serious goal...).

The program works correctly: it searches images on a series  of web-sites stored on a list, and downloads one randomly and automatically. The problem is that some pictures are not fully downloaded: their size is much smaller than the pictures correctly downloaded, and, when opened, won't show any image.

Why are some pictures downloaded fine, and others, though the file is there, are so small in size and show no image when opened? Where am I making a mistake?

I really want to correct this. I am really new on Python, so any other advises are more than welcome (mostly if they are related to a way of reducing that messy bunch of code I made on the look_images(x, z) function, with all those try, except and while loops codes and stuff...). Thank you! Here's the script:

```
#! python3

import os, requests, bs4, random, shelve, wget

def create_folder(): #Creates the folder 'Puppies'
    print('Comprobando pelusitas y pulguitas...')
    os.makedirs('Puppies', exist_ok=True)

def download_image(url, request_response): #Saves the image in the folder 'Puppies'
    image_file = open(os.path.join('Puppies', os.path.basename(url)), 'wb')
    for chunk in request_response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
        image_file.write(chunk)
        image_file.flush()
    image_file.close()

def create_saves(saves_list): #Creates a data file, if not yet created, storing the pictures already downloaded.
    if os.path.isfile('C:\\Users\\usuario\\Documents\\santi\\saves.dat') == False:
        page_files = shelve.open('saves')
        page_files['saves'] = saves_list
        page_files.close()

def look_images(pages_list, saves_list):


    for i in pages_list: #For every item in the pages_list (for every page...)
        res = requests.get(i)
        res.raise_for_status()
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
        object = soup.select('img')
        object_number = len(object)
        random_number = random.randint(0, int(object_number)) #Creates a random number between 0 and the number of images the object variable found.

        print('\nSe encontraron {} cachorritos potenciales...'.format(int(object_number)))
        try:
            image_url = object[random_number].get('srcset')
        except IndexError:
            print('No se hallaron vauitos, se continuará la búsqueda...')
        print('\nEvaluando colmillitos y patitas...')
        page_files = shelve.open('saves') #Opens the saves data file.
        while str(image_url) in open('saves.dat', encoding='Latin-1').read(): #While the image found is stored in the saves.dat file, select another image.
            try:
                image_url = object[random.randint(0, int(object_number))].get('src')
            except IndexError:
                continue
        while not '.jpg' in str(image_url):
            try:
                image_url = object[random.randint(0, int(object_number))].get('src')
                if str(image_url) in open('saves.dat', encoding='Latin-1').read():
                    image_url = object[random.randint(0, int(object_number))].get('src')
                    continue
            except IndexError:
                    print('No se hallaron vauitos, se continuará la búsqueda...')
                    continue
        print('\nSe encontraron vauitos...')
        print('\nAdoptando cachorrito...')
        if str(image_url).endswith('.jpg 2x'): #Lot of images were downloaded as '.jpg 2x', so I made this if statement to erase the ' 2x' final part.
            image_url = str(image_url.replace(' ', '')[:-2])
        response = requests.get(image_url, stream=True)
        res.raise_for_status()
        saves_list.append(image_url) #Adds the image to the save_list, which is then saved on the .dat 'saves' file.

        download_image(image_url, response)
        print('¡Cachorrito adoptado!')

        page_files[image_url] = page_files #Saves the image url on the 'saves'.dat file
        page_files.close()


def get_page():

    page = ['https://pixabay.com/es/photos/puppy/',
    'https://www.petsworld.in/blog/cute-pictures-of-puppies-and-kittens-together.html',
    'https://pixabay.com/es/photos/bear%20cubs/',
    'https://pixabay.com/es/photos/?q=cute+little+animals&hp=&image_type=photo&order=popular&cat=',
    'https://pixabay.com/es/photos/?q=baby+cows&hp=&image_type=photo&order=popular&cat=',
    'https://www.boredpanda.com/cute-baby-animals/',
    'http://abduzeedo.com/node/74367']
    alr_dow = []

    create_folder()
    create_saves(alr_dow)
    look_images(page, alr_dow)

get_page()
```

P.S. The printed messages are in Spanish and are irrelevant to the question. Please note that the goal is to make this a serious program at some time, downloading serious things.

The problem has been solved. Apparently, it was a problem raised when requesting the url of the images of some of the pages. I didn't notice this error because of a mistake of mine, at the end of the look_images function: the "res.raise_for_status()" should have been "response.raise_for_status()", since "response" was the variable that stored the request of the image url. When corrected that, I noticed that on the second and the last page of the pages list a request error was being raised: from this sites were the files that didn't download properly, due to an error apparently related to some port and firewall issues. This is the code now, properly functioning and also cleaner than the first:

```
#! python3

import os, requests, bs4, random, shelve, shutil

def create_folder():
    print('Comprobando pelusitas y pulguitas...')
    os.makedirs('Puppies', exist_ok=True)

def download_image_shutil(url, request_response):

    local_filename = url.split('/')[-1]
    with open(os.path.join('Puppies', local_filename), 'wb') as f:
        shutil.copyfileobj(request_response.raw, f, [False])

    return local_filename

def create_saves(saves_list):
    if os.path.isfile('C:\\Users\\usuario\\Documents\\santi\\saves.dat') == False:
        page_files = shelve.open('saves')
        page_files['saves'] = saves_list
        page_files.close()

def get_random_url(web_object, web_object_number):

    while True:
        try:
            random_number = random.randint(0, web_object_number)
            url_variable = web_object[random_number].get('src')
            if not '.jpg' in str(url_variable):
                continue
            elif str(url_variable) in open('saves.dat', encoding='Latin-1').read():
                continue
            print('Finish')
            print(url_variable)
            return url_variable
            break
        except IndexError:
            print('Algo salió mal: reanundando búsqueda...')
            continue

def look_images(pages_list, saves_list):


    for i in pages_list:
        res = requests.get(i)
        res.raise_for_status()
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
        object = soup.select('img')
        object_number = len(object)

        print('\nSe encontraron {} cachorritos potenciales...'.format(int(object_number)))
        print('\nEvaluando colmillitos y patitas...')
        page_files = shelve.open('saves')
        image_url = get_random_url(object, object_number)
        print('\nSe encontraron vauitos...')
        print('\nAdoptando cachorrito...')
        if str(image_url).endswith('.jpg 2x'):
            image_url = str(image_url.replace(' ', '')[:-2])
        if not str(image_url).startswith('https://'):
            image_url = 'https://' + str(image_url)
        response = requests.get(image_url, stream=True)
        response.raise_for_status()
        saves_list.append(image_url)

        download_image_shutil(image_url, response)
        print('¡Cachorrito adoptado!')

        page_files[image_url] = page_files
        page_files.close()


def get_page():

    page = ['https://pixabay.com/es/photos/puppy/',
    'https://www.petsworld.in/blog/cute-pictures-of-puppies-and-kittens-together.html',
    'https://pixabay.com/es/photos/bear%20cubs/',
    'https://pixabay.com/es/photos/?q=cute+little+animals&hp=&image_type=photo&order=popular&cat=',
    'https://pixabay.com/es/photos/?q=baby+cows&hp=&image_type=photo&order=popular&cat=',
    'https://www.boredpanda.com/cute-baby-animals/']
    alr_dow = []

    create_folder()
    create_saves(alr_dow)
    look_images(page, alr_dow)

get_page()
```

I converted some variables to strings (with the str(x) function) because if not an error saying: NoneType is not iterable appeared on the variables. I didn't understand where that came from; if someone could tell me, would be nice.

I express my gratitude towards bruno desthuilliers, who advised me well and had the patience to do so.

Comment: `os.path.basename(url)` is certainly not a good idea - `os.path` is about filesystem path, not urls.  You probably want to use the `urlparse` module and/or something based on `.rstrip("/").split("/")[-1]` instead.

Comment: And here `print('\nSe encontraron {} cachorritos potenciales...'.format(int(object_number)))` `object_number` is already an int.

Comment: Mmm, quite a lot of useless `int(someint)` and `str(somestr)` here, plus opening the same file(s) again and again without closing them, plus using relative filesystem path all along (relative path are resolved against the current working directory, not against the directory where the script lives).

Comment: Yes, I know there's a lot of that :( If I don't convert to string the image_url variable I get an error for some reason, that's why I always use str(image_url) here. About the int(whatever), I removed those when I read your other comment.

Comment: "If I don't convert to string the image_url variable I get an error for some reason, that's why I always use str(image_url) here" => the error should come with an error message and a traceback giving you hints about what went wrong, where and possibly why. Rule #1 : don't mask the symptom but fix the real problem. But well all this is very probably unrelated.

Comment: Sure, thanks bruno, you're right. I will try to solve that issue and if I can't perhaps I'll comment here the error message with the traceback. I am very new at Python... Thanks!

Comment: According to a quick google search, there might be some occasional issues with `response.iter_contents`/`file.write`, depending on the environment, server, phase of the moon and whatnots, cf https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/4227 and https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/2043. A first step in debugging would be to 1/ print out the `Content-length` and `Content-encoding` response headers (if set), then print out the effective file size (after the file is closed and using `os.stat`), and 2/ try downloading the same images without streaming to find out if it's ok this way.

Comment: Also you may want to try the `shutil.copyfile` / `response.raw` solution explained in the second answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907/

Comment: As a last note: when having this kind of problems, try to reduce your code to the minimum needed to consistenly reproduce the problem - this is called a MCVE  ('minimal complete verifiable example' cf https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will make it easier for other people to help you debug the problem, and actually it often let you find the problem by yourself ;)

Comment: This has been very helpful, Bruno. Only two things:

a) Changed the script; I am currently using shutil.copyfile as you suggested: the problem hasn't been solved. I am keeping the shutil module nevertheless; uses less code and works faster.

b) Tonight I'll begin to work on the MCVE: so helpful! Thank you very much.

Comment: Solved, thank you! More details on the edition of the post itself.